# how to properly use mockbuilder from phpunit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, reflection, mocking, phpunit

I'm trying to mock one of my class using phpunit mockbuilder but I only want the 'index' method. But When I try with the code below, the var_dump indicates I have all the methods from my class in the mock?? Is that normal? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
public function setUp(): void
        {
            parent::setUp();
    
            $mockController = $this->getMockBuilder(MyClass::class)
                                    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                                    ->disableOriginalClone()
                                    ->disableArgumentCloning()
                                    ->disallowMockingUnknownTypes()
                                    ->setMethods(['index'])
                                    ->getMock();
                                    
            var_dump(get_class_methods($mockController));
        }
```

Edit: result of var_dump:

```
array(18) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "index"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "__construct"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "launch"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "continue"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "setCss"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "setJs"
  [6]=>
  string(4) "meta"
  [7]=>
  string(6) "render"
  [8]=>
  string(14) "initController"
  [9]=>
  string(33) "__phpunit_initConfigurableMethods"
  [10]=>
  string(27) "__phpunit_setOriginalObject"
  [11]=>
  string(34) "__phpunit_setReturnValueGeneration"
  [12]=>
  string(30) "__phpunit_getInvocationHandler"
  [13]=>
  string(21) "__phpunit_hasMatchers"
  [14]=>
  string(16) "__phpunit_verify"
  [15]=>
  string(7) "expects"
  [16]=>
  string(6) "method"
  [17]=>
  string(7) "__clone"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: try using `->makePartial()` and `->shouldReceive('index')`

Comment: I can't use Mockery

Answer (score 0):

My advice: RUN. PHPUnit is going down, because its author makes it increasingly opinionated and keeps removing and removing and removing and removing and removing features with utter disregard for either existing uses or even basic doability-of-things. Look for alternatives, or stick to older versions of PHPUnit that still have useful features.